# Lookup between 2 sheets

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to figure out what items in a specific range in Sheet1 are written in column A in sheet 2.
if the item is in both sheets - it will be colored in sheet1.

at the moment the Code is almost working but it colors all the items and it should color only those appear in both sheets.

- Sheet1:

[image: Sheet1]

- Sheet2: You can see the values: game1, game2, cat4 are missing.

[image: Sheet2]

- Output I want to get:

[image: Output I want to get]

So far I tried:

```
Sub Sample()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Result

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:H9")
        On Error Resume Next
        Result = Application.XLookup(cell, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"), 1, True)
        'On Error GoTo 0

       If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            'If cell = Result Then
                cell.Font.Bold = True
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                cell.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
            'End If
            Result = ""
        End If
        
        'If cell = "Error 2042" Then
            'nothing found
        'ElseIf cell = Result Then
            'cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        'End If
        
    Next
    
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `XLookup`? Make sure `On Error GoTo 0` is NOT a comment or `On Error Resume Next` is never used alone without `On Error GoTo 0` or proper error handling. If you use it alone you cannot debug your code properly because you cannot see your errors. See [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - it's a new lookup function in 365.

Comment: @SJR Ah my bad I'm still on 2019 version.

Comment: Your code does the formatting etc as long as the cell is not empty, it is not dependent on the result of the lookup, and that does not look right to me. In any case the XMATCH function might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Ordinary `Match` would do, I don't know what is the advantage of XMATCH.

You could also do this with conditional formatting (with or without VBA).

```
Sub Sample()

Dim cell As Range
Dim Result

For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:H9")
    Result = Application.XMatch(cell, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"), 0)
    If Isnumeric(Result) Then 'no match
        cell.Font.Bold = True
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        cell.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    End If
Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This code is formatting for me only the cells that aren't in range in sheet2 column A. What should I change?

Comment: worked! thanks. In addition, is that a correct way to implement the script if I got more than 800 rows and 30 columns in sheet1?

Comment: Could you get in the habit of accepting answers please? That should be fine for that amount of data.